# Update field number in ms access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table called table books in Microsoft Access. In this table there is a field called availability which means the number of books up till now. My question is how to use update query to add number x to the value in field availability.

Update field in MS Access.

Comment: Please share sample data and desired results after this operation occurs. The information you have provided so far is not enough for us to understand well enough to help.

Comment: `UPDATE [Books] SET [Availability] = [xxx] WHERE [ID] = [xxx]`.

Comment: Really should not do this. Should just enter transaction records and calculate balances when needed. Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

Comment: You can do it in 3 steps.
1. Lookup Availability
`Availability = dLookup ("Availability", "Books", "ID=" & trim(str(ID)))`
2. Add the number of books you want, for example 5 pieces:
`Availability = Availability + 5`
3. Update the record:
`docmd.runsql ("UPDATE Books SET Availability=" & trim(str(Availability)) & " WHERE ID=" & trim(str(ID)))`